# How do i call a function with an event in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components: `pictures` and `camera`, with `camera` being the child.

In `camera` i have this typescript (short version of course):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-camera',
  templateUrl: './camera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./camera.component.scss']
})
export class CameraComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output('onPictureTaken') picture = new EventEmitter<WebcamImage>();
  public webcamImage: WebcamImage;
  pictureTaken(){
    this.picture.emit(this.webcamImage)
}
```

and this html:
`<button class="actionBtn" (click)="pictureTaken();">Take A Snapshot</button>`

in `pictures` i have this code instead. Typescript:

```
export class PicturesComponent implements OnInit {
 // @Output('picture') picture: WebcamImage;
  public pictures: WebcamImage[]
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onPictureTaken(picture: WebcamImage){
    this.pictures.push(picture)
    console.log("picture taken!!!")
  }
}
```

and this html:

```
<app-camera ></app-camera>
<table>
    <caption>Photos: </caption>
    <tr (onPictureTaken)="onPictureTaken($any($event))"> </tr>
</table>
```

No matter what i try i never reach the function `onPictureTaken` and i never see the log 'picture taken!!!' in the console.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the event binding in the wrong place. The emitter is defined for your component `app-camera`, but you've placed it in the `tr` tag.

So instead of

```
<app-camera ></app-camera>
<table>
  <caption>Photos: </caption>
  <tr (onPictureTaken)="onPictureTaken($event)"> </tr>
</table>
```

You need to move it to your component

```
<app-camera (onPictureTaken)="onPictureTaken($event)"></app-camera>
<table>
  <caption>Photos: </caption>
  <tr> </tr>
</table>
```